# XNA 4.0 resources not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

I'm using XNA 4.0 with VS 2010. When I start a new project, a decent amount of the resources have broken links; other sites where people have encountered this problem suggest manually fixing the file paths, which works but is bothersome when I'm creating several new projects (I'm following various tutorials to learn my way around XNA). Does anyone know if there is a way to fix the underlying problem, rather than changing the file paths for each new project?

Comment: More information? Screenshots? Full error readouts? Links to those "other sites"?

Comment: It tries to add resources and can't find them. The warning gives no more information than I already have (The referenced component 'Microsoft.XNA.Framework.xxx' could not be found.) Here are a few links, since you asked: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/583058-xna-challenge-2-could-not-resolve-this-reference/ (somebody else with the same problem) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/09/17/10064091.aspx (I have never installed the beta version so the bulk of this page does apply. Apparently that causes the same problem though, so I used the solution here.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use Contents of other project in one solution ? Than you add to your Content Project Reference's the external Content you want to use. Jon's answer is already works fine, I already prefer Jon's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put your resources in the Content directory, then copy the Content directory to your new project, it should retain all the files and the links should still be good.

Not sure what the problem is exactly, possibly provide more information on the problem so that we can get a better idea of what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not trying to use any custom resources; the links to the XNA resources that are automatically added to new projects are broken (Microsoft.XNA.Framework.xxx).

Comment: Take a look in your GAC to see if you have the XNA framework installed properly.  (typically in C:\Windows\assembly). You should see Microsoft.XNA.Framework.  Your project should be referencing these DLLs, if you choose Game Project it does this automatically.